# Man Who Disappears Due To Depression?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to remember a novel I read in the early aughts (I think) about a man (or possibly teen) who gradually fades from society and eventually disappears entirely.

I don't think it's Fade by Robert Cormier. I read it at a similar time, and maybe I'm mixing up details. I seem to recall depression/neglect being somewhat causal in the disappearance, though.

The only other detail I even vaguely remember is an urban setting, possibly New York.

Comment: Somewhat reminiscent of ["The Strange Case of Lemuel Jenkins"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?70686) by [Philip M. Fisher](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/fisher_philip_m_jr) which you can read at [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/Donald_A._Wollheim_ed._Avon_Fantasy_Reader_no._2_1947#page/n25/mode/2up). But that's just a novelette, and I believe it's set in California.

Comment: I think that's far too old, and it was a full length novel. Thanks though!

Comment: When you say "disappears entirely," just how literally do you mean that ? The poor guy becomes invisible so that no one can see him? Or he fades away into thin air and no longer exists? Or what?

Comment: I don't remember specifically. I think he disappeared, but still existed. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5):

[Are You Listening?](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56352) by Harlan Ellison, is a short story about a man who is so innocuous and quiet that he becomes invisible and incapable of interacting with reality. He can see and hear them, even hitting people at one point, but they seem not to notice or react to his presence. Even his wife can't see him, and eventually begins to forget he ever existed.

Comment: This story looks and sounds like it could be right, but I'll need some time to confirm. I don't remember the main character being married. I thought he was a teenager. I also remember it being a novel, though possibly a short one.

Answer (score 4):

["The Vanishing American"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40826) by Charles Beaumont is a similar story about a businessman whose life is so unremarkable that he begins to disappear until a radical act (climbing atop a stone lion outside the NY public library) brings him back.

The story originally appeared in the [Aug, 1955 issue of F&SF](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v009n02_1955-08/page/n96) and has been included in a number of SF anthologies.